# Firebase: Google api key restriction doesn't work

Tags: firebase, google-api

Firebase created for me an API key on Google API console. There I added a restriction to make it usable only by an Android app with a specific package name and fingerprint.

However I can still use the key with a different package name (I changed the application Id for Gradle). What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't attempt to restrict usage of Realtime Database based on the host app's application ID or signing hash.  When you create a new Android app in the console, you'll notice the following text under the text field for signing key:

> Required for Dynamic Links, Invites, and Google Sign-In support in
>   Auth. Edit SHA-1s in Settings.

These are the only Firebase features that are affected by the application ID and signing hash.  The reason an application ID is require is to help the Gradle plugin match a google-services.json file to the app it was built for.  It's *not* a security measure.

If you change your application ID in build.gradle but don't create a new app and download a new google-services.json file, your build should fail with this message:

> No matching client found for package name 'your.new.package.name'

Comment: You can change the id in build.gradle, then directly edit the app package name in google-service.json in the same way. To my surprise you can connect to the backend even if that fake app name doesn't exist on the Firebase console.

Comment: If you do that, then every change you make in your project that requires a new google-services.json will also require you to edit it again.  And again.  Bear in mind also that the database security rules are designed so that you can configure it to be world-accessible.  Again, that file you download is *not* a security measure.  The values in it get baked right into your app, and anyone can reverse engineer them.  If you need security, then also use Firebase Authentication.